# VS Code replacing all TypeScript path aliases with single backslash character

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, expo, alias

I'm currently working on a React Native app using Expo, and the project has TypeScript path aliases set up. The aliases seem to work fine; imports resolve correctly, and the app builds as expected. However, VS Code never correctly autocompletes the path aliases when writing `import` statements.

For example, when I'm typing an `import` statement, the alias is correctly suggested:

[image: Correct alias is suggested]

But when I accept the autocomplete, the alias is replaced with a backslash, and I have to type it out manually:

[image: Alias is not included in autocomplete result]

Here's `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "$components": ["App/components/index"],
      "$components/*": ["App/components/*"],
      "$constants": ["App/constants/index"],
      "$constants/*": ["App/constants/*"],
      "$helpers": ["App/helpers/index"],
      "$helpers/*": ["App/helpers/*"],
      "$navigators": ["App/navigators/index"],
      "$navigators/*": ["App/navigators/*"],
      "$screens": ["App/screens/index"],
      "$screens/*": ["App/screens/*"],
      "$services": ["App/services/index"],
      "$services/*": ["App/services/*"],
      "$api/*": ["App/services/api/*"],
      "$state": ["App/state/index"],
      "$state/*": ["App/state/*"],
      "$themes": ["App/themes/index"],
      "$themes/*": ["App/themes/*"],
      "$types": ["App/types/index"],
      "$types/*": ["App/types/*"],
      "$tests/*": ["tests/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

And the `expo/tsconfig.base.json` that it extends:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Expo",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["DOM", "ESNext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "ESNext"
  },

  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"]
}
```

Any idea why these autocompletes are failing? It's a relatively minor issue at the end of the day, but frustrating nonetheless.

I've been Googling for solutions but haven't been able to find anyone with a similar issue. I did try making minor changes to `tsconfig`, like including a slash in `baseURL`. I also tried modifying VS Code's `settings.json` to include `"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative"`.